# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error while converting string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert string to datetime in c#. I tried below

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2014 11:48:25","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

But i get error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

I tried doing `Convert.ToDateTime` but it cuts off the hours,minutes and seconds.

How to get rid of this problem?

**Update1**
I had also tried using like

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2014 11:48:25","dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

But still i get same error

**Update2**
After using code

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2014 11:48:25","dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

its working fine. But what if date is passed as  `"01/01/2014 11:48:25"` then this format wont work.

Comment: Just take a look at the format string you supply. Does it even look like it uses the same format as "01.01.2014 11:48:25"?

Comment: @Dirk Well i had tried both using yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss and dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: Use the same delimiter in both strings. You're using hyphen and punctation like they're the same.

Comment: what if date is passed as "01/01/2014 11:48:25" - you can use the DateTime.ParseExact overload that takes an array of allowable formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` object provides three overload of `ParseExact()` method. You could try using the following overload to converts the specified `string` to its `DateTime` equivalent using the specified array of formats:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
```

Example:

```
...
// define the possible date formats
var formats = new[] {
  "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
  "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
  "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
};

DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2014 11:48:25", formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2014 11:48:25", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: But what happens if i get string like 01/012014 11:48:25